AWS CodeDeploy with Bitbucket pipe line
I'm trying to deploy AWS EC2 deployment using the Bitbucket pipeline and the AWS code deployment.
I'm getting this error when trying to deploy. It mentions some errors related to Auto Scaling groups but EC2 doesn't have any.
INFO: {'deploymentInfo': {'applicationName': 'test', 'deploymentGroupName': 'test', 'deploymentConfigName': 'CodeDeployDefault.AllAtOnce', 'deploymentId': 'd-46ZFG88M4', 'revision': {'revisionType': 'S3', 's3Location': {'bucket': 'bitbucket-test-180209879932', 'key': 'test/test-1.0.0', 'bundleType': 'zip'}}, 'status': 'Failed', 'errorInformation': {'code': 'NO_INSTANCES', 'message': 'The deployment failed because no instances were found for your deployment group. Check your deployment group settings to make sure the tags for your Amazon EC2 instances or Auto Scaling groups correctly identify the instances you want to deploy to, and then try again.'}, 'createTime': datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 18, 9, 44, 54, 783000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'completeTime': datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 18, 9, 44, 56, 535000, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'description': 'Deployed from Bitbucket Pipelines using aws-code-deploy pipe. For details follow the link https://bitbucket.org/test/123/addon/pipelines/home#!/results/38', 'creator': 'user', 'ignoreApplicationStopFailures': False, 'updateOutdatedInstancesOnly': False, 'rollbackInfo': {}, 'deploymentStyle': {'deploymentType': 'IN_PLACE', 'deploymentOption': 'WITHOUT_TRAFFIC_CONTROL'}, 'instanceTerminationWaitTimeStarted': False, 'fileExistsBehavior': 'OVERWRITE', 'deploymentStatusMessages': [], 'computePlatform': 'Server'}, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'ba4f1d61-ac30-457f-924b-560b982396cf', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'ba4f1d61-ac30-457f-924b-560b982396cf', 'date': 'Thu, 18 Apr 2024 09:45:11 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'content-length': '1244', 'connection': 'keep-alive'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}


✖ Error waiting for deployment successful: Waiter DeploymentSuccessful
failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression
"deploymentInfo.status" we matched expected path: "Failed"

